# Python lxml, removing parent elements before outputting HTML (using fragment_fromstring)

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

I'm using lxml to parse some HTML fragments (from a RSS feed), and in order to do this efficiently I use the `create_parent='div'`. When i later output the HTML I don't want the parent div to be included since with my html layout it ends up being a div in a div, totally unnessecary.

The code as is now:

```
from lxml.html import fragment_fromstring

html = fragment_fromstring(html_string, create_parent = 'div')

for tag in html.xpath('//*[@class]'):
    tag.attrib.pop('class')
for tag in html.xpath('//*[@id]'):
    tag.attrib.pop('id')

return lxml.html.tostring(html)
```

TL;DR: how do I remove the wrapping div when it outputs?

Comment: This is probably the answer; "remove the wrapping div" by stepping over it and passing the child in: `lxml.etree.tostring( html_doc.xpath('*')[0] )`. Warning: Untested code. Only been using python lxml for 15 years. Whoever runs the test on that code change should write the answer note.

Answer (score 2):

Extract child elements.

```
return '\n'.join(lxml.html.tostring(x) for x in html.iterchildren())
```

Comment: But that's not extracting the text nodes

Comment: @Hemant_Negi, Do you want something like: `html.text_content().strip()` ?

Comment: i want all the content inside the element which. can contain html nodes as text. i think this is returning only the text.

Comment: @Hemant_Negi, Try solutions in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19835881/2225682). If that does not solve your problem, please post a separated question so that others can help you.