# lxml xml parsing with html tags inside xml tags

Tags: python, html, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

```
<xml>
<maintag>    
<content> lorem <br>ipsum</br> <strong> dolor sit </strong> and so on </content>
</maintag>
</xml>
```

The xml file that I regularly parse, may have HTML tags inside of content tag as shown above.

Here how I parse the file:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=False)
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xmlFile), parser)
for item in tree.iter('maintag'):
  my_content = item.find('content').text
  #print my_content
  #output: lorem
```

as a result it results my_content = '*lorem*' instead of -which i'd like to see- ' lorem < br >ipsum< /br> < strong > dolor sit < /strong > and so on'

How can I read the content as  ' lorem < br>ipsum< /br> < strong > dolor sit < /strong > and so on'?

**Note:** content tag may have another html tags instead of strong. And may not have them at all.

Comment: The HTML tags are just XML tags with names identical to HML tags. That doesn't make them HTML. In HTML, the `<br />` tag is *empty* for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring('''<xml>
<maintag>    
<content> lorem <br>ipsum</br> <strong> dolor sit </strong> and so on </content>
</maintag>
</xml>''')
for content in root.xpath('.//maintag/content'):
    print etree.tostring(content)
```

prints

```
<content> lorem <br>ipsum</br> <strong> dolor sit </strong> and so on </content>
```

---

```
....
for content in root.xpath('.//maintag/content'):
    print ''.join(child if isinstance(child, basestring) else etree.tostring(child)
                  for child in content.xpath('*|text()'))
```

prints

```
 lorem <br>ipsum</br>  <strong> dolor sit </strong> and so on  and so on
```